# Apache Spark: is it possible to get dataset counts in a spark job?

Tags: apache-spark

Sometimes some Spark job which runs in our cluster runs too long not because of bad optimization, but because of bad logic of the algorithm. In most cases this is a consequence of some unnecessary joins that produce too many rows. Normally we spot such jobs by looking at Spark execution plan where we can find such joins by looking at "number of output rows: xxx" in blue stage labels.

I want to understand - is it possible to optimize this procedure and somehow automatically notify the programmer that the job has too many rows in some dataset (after execution)?

Maybe we can print this in logs (without manually counting dataset's size in code)?
Maybe after running the job we can get the output of the execution plan somehow and save it for further investigations?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not an option. Spark will do its best to [optimize the query plan](https://databricks.com/glossary/catalyst-optimizer), so manual interaction with lower execution level is pretty much limited. However, you can "control" the rows for each jobs/tasks by changing some configurations (like `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` or `spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes`), or by [repartitioning](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.repartition) data, which will cause data to be shuffled and re-distributed **nearly** equally between executors.